# Receive Consumption REQUEST NOTIFY and Send Consumption Info

Tags: jwt, apple-push-notifications

apple will send a Consumption_Request notify to merchant server if user start a refund.
When I tried to process the Consumption Request notify and call the Send Consumption Info interface to send user consumption info to apple server, I got two forms of response.

case 1 :

when my param is wrong , the response like this :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS4wF.png)

case 2 :

when my param is right , the response code is 401 ,like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFDtN.png)

And I found 401 mean Unauthorized . So maybe my JWT check failed.

SO my question is how do you generate your JWT token? Is any demo ?
and how do you get your secret key file(the .p8 file. I suspect that I got a wrong file)?

Comment: and I call the  "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps" interface succed. WHY???

Answer (score 0):

> how do you generate your JWT token?

here is one sample by golang

```golang
func readPrivateKeyFromFile(keyFile string) (*ecdsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(keyFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode(bytes)
    if block == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("appstore private key must be a valid .p8 PEM file")
    }

    key, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    switch pk := key.(type) {
    case *ecdsa.PrivateKey:
        return pk, nil
    default:
        return nil, errors.New("appstore private key must be of type ecdsa.PrivateKey")
    }

}

func generateToken(privateKey *ecdsa.PrivateKey) (string, error) {
    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodES256, jwt.MapClaims{
        "iss":   "issuerId,
        "isa":   time.Now().Unix(),
        "exp":   expireTIme,
        "aud":   "appstoreconnect-v1",
        "nonce": "uuid",
        "bid":   "bid",
    })

    token.Header["kid"] = "keyId"
    token.Header["alg"] = "ES256"
    token.Header["typ"] = "JWT"

    return token.SignedString(privateKey)
}
```

> how do you get your secret key file(the .p8 file. I suspect that I got a wrong file)?

Please refer to doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/creating_api_keys_to_use_with_the_app_store_server_api?changes=latest_major